# Liferay Module Project Fragment, missing Liferay Runtime Name

Tags: eclipse, fragment, liferay, hook

I have Eclipse Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)

I have a server: `Liferay Community Edition Portal 7.2.1 CE GA2`

I wanto to create a hook (Liferay Module Project Fragment) but eclipse doesn't let me choose `Liferay Runtime envoirment name`

How i can choose it? what am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution to your issue, here are my reproduction + solution steps:

1. I downloaded Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)) to ensure I am getting the same error as you
2. Followed the official article to set up Liferay within Eclipse (https://help.liferay.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017897772-Developing-Applications-with-Liferay-IDE) (the article is for 6.2 but the process has not changed)
3. I created an Eclipse workspace, and then a separate Liferay workspace within the Eclipse workspace (please note that both are needed)
4. Within Eclipse I switched to the Liferay perspectivate, and started to create a new Liferay Module Project Fragment
   Checkpoint:  I could not select my runtime, just like you
5. I exited Eclipse, and visited the Liferay workspace directory
6. Within that directory, I opened the gradle.properties file and added this line:
   liferay.workspace.home.dir=/home/USER/stackoverflow/liferay-dxp-7.2.10-ga1
7. Re-started Eclipse and this time, the runtime was selected in the new project wizard window

   Hope this helps!

Comment: I edited the file ma it doesn't work. I use Windows and i set this path: liferay.workspace.home.dir=C:\Users\myuser\myspace\liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2

Comment: I set liferay.workspace.home.dir=../liferay-ce-portal-7.2.1-ga2. Now It works!

Comment: What worked for me, as a developer who downloaded the Liferay Tomcat bundle, was editing the file `gradle.properties` and add the following line: liferay.workspace.home.dir = bundles/tomcat-9.0.17